# Nltk's wordnet lemmatizer not lemmatizing all words

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet, lemmatization

I'm trying to lemmatize words in a text. Like for example 'pickled' should turn to 'pickle', 'ran' to 'run', 'raisins' to 'raisin' etc.

I'm using nltk's `WordNet Lemmatizer` as follows:

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
>>> 
>>> lem = WordNetLemmatizer()
>>> print(lem.lemmatize("cats"))
cat
>>> print(lem.lemmatize("pickled"))
pickled
>>> print(lem.lemmatize("ran"))
ran
```

So, as you can see for `'pickled'` and `'ran'`, the output isn't coming as expected. How to get `'pickle'` and `'run'` for these without having to specify `'v'` (verb) etc. for the words.

Comment: How about [POS tagging](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html#nltk.tag.pos_tag)?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the base form of `lemmatize()` function for a noun or a verb by getting the most common result of the function among passing a `'v'` or `'n'` parameter and not passing anything.

Not a direct way to do but you can try the following code for getting the base form of a noun or a verb:

```
def most_common(lst):
    return max(set(lst), key=lst.count)
words = ['ran','pickled','cats',"crying","died","raisins","had"]
for word in words:
    checkList=[WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(word,'v'),WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(word,'n'),WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(word,'n')]
    print most_common(checkList)
```

You get the base form :

```
ran
pickled
cat
cry
died
raisin
had
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I do not want to intput 'v', coz it's a huge text and I can't do it for every word. Or probably is there a way?

Comment: Made an update to the answer. Hope that works for you